# Is it a good practice to override DataBind() method on a a user control?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

Is it a good practice to ovverride DataBind() method of the user controls? Or to have a separate method (like ReBind() ) is better way?

Comment: It's an old question but i can reply if you want :D

Answer (score 0):

For user controls is better suited a custom binding of your data, in order to do so you should:

1. Store your data in the control state (use `ViewState` or `ControlState`)
2. Set a public method that bind the data to your control (like `BindData`)
3. Check if on post-backs some change is needed; if so, use again `BindData`

**References**

- [Control State vs. View State Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1whwt1k7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [An Extensive Examination of User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx)